# Magento 2 - Where to store big JSON

Tags: magento2

1. In my store each customer has own big JSON array (about 1,5K items).
2. The JSON array is updated regurarly (so it can't be cached)
3. At the moment, every time JSON data is needed, it's being pull from database. It need for all product pages.

Is there any way, to cache the JSON data (redis, local storage, etc) for each user in a way so that it can be easily updated when required?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Store JSON data in file system  lets say in `var/json/UNIQUE.json`
2. Store `UNIQUE` in `customer_entity` (or customer attribute)
3. Fetch data from Block (Vendor/Module/Block/JFetch.php)
4. Implement caching with time limit(here 1 hour):

Block Sample

```
<referenceContainer name="xxx">
    <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\JFetch" before="-" name="xxx" template="xxx.phtml" cacheable="true" ttl="3600"/>
</referenceContainer>
```